# How to select all child div with same class using Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm new for Puppeteer and I'm trying to get textContent from two divs that using same class.

```
<div class="post-item">
   <div class="post-item-info">
      <span class="post-item-status post-comment"></span>
      3
   </div>
   <div class="post-item-info">
      <span class="post-item-status post-vote"></span>
      5
   </div>
</div>
```

The result that I'm expecting is return an array [3,5]. My current code is below.

```
let postInfo = element.querySelector('.post-item-info');
```

The problem is it is only return the first one. Please let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your selector should be like `const nodes = element.querySelectorAll('.post-item-info');`. Then to access individual items in the returned collection, use a traditional for loop like

```
for(let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){
      const currentNode = nodes[i];
      // doStuffWith(currentNode);
    }
```

Comment: Or use `Array.from` for a more elegant way :)

Comment: True, or even shorter, `[...nodes]` should also work.

Answer (score 3):

Some concise ways to get the array of these text contents:

```js
   const texts = await page.$$eval('.post-item-info',
     divs => divs.map(({ innerText }) => innerText));
```

```js
    const texts = await page.evaluate(() =>
      [...document.querySelectorAll('.post-item-info'')].map(({ innerText }) => innerText));
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, there's a similar method for that [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```
const nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.post-item-info')

Array.from(nodes).forEach(node => {
  // do stuff with node
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Get them like:

```
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('post-item-info')
```

It returns an array and then you can loop on it. Also, you can see this Github question for the same case:

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/461