# Copy inner text of elements with same classes but in order (puppeteer)

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

There is a wrapper and each have a container with title, description, and other info but all of the titles, descriptions, and other details have the same class name. I have tried `querySelectorAll` that I found here [How to select all child div with same class using Puppeteer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54677126/how-to-select-all-child-div-with-same-class-using-puppeteer)

but it can't get the elements. I need to get them each in order so they stay organized. Here is what one of the containers looks like

```
<
div class = "cms-article-list__content--container" >
    <
    div class = "cms-article-list__title-number-panel" >
    <
    span class = "cms-article-list__title-number" > 1 < /span> <
    /div>

    <
    div class = "cms-article-list__content--group" >
    <
    div class = "cms-article-list__content--group-title" > BARBELL BENCH PRESS(WARM - UP SETS) < /div>

    <
    div class = "cms-article-list__content--group-description" > Use light weight and perform 2 sets of 5 - 10 reps, stopping each set short of failure. < /div>





    <
    div class = "cms-article-list__content" >
    <
    div class = "cms-article-list__content--container-left" >
    <
    div class = "cms-article-workout__exercise--info" >
    <
    a target = "_blank"
href = "//www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/detail/view/name/barbell-bench-press-medium-grip"
class = "cms-article-workout__exercise--title" > Barbell Bench Press - Medium Grip < /a> <
    div class = "cms-article-workout__exercise--description" > < /div> <
    /div>

    <
    div class = "cms-article-workout__sets--definition" >
    <
    span > 2 sets, 5 - 10 reps(rest 1 min.) < /span> <
    /div>

    <
    /div> <
    a target = "_blank"
href = "//www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/detail/view/name/barbell-bench-press-medium-grip"
class = "cms-article-list__content--container-right" >
    <
    img class = "cms-article-workout__exercise--img cms-article-workout__exercise--img-left"
src = "https://www.bodybuilding.com/images/2020/xdb/cropped/xdb-81e-bench-press-m1-square-130x130.jpg"
srcset = "https://www.bodybuilding.com/images/2020/xdb/cropped/xdb-81e-bench-press-m1-square-130x130.jpg 1x, https://www.bodybuilding.com/images/2020/xdb/cropped/xdb-81e-bench-press-m1-square-200x200.jpg 2x" >
    <img class = "cms-article-workout__exercise--img cms-article-workout__exercise--img-right"
src = "https://www.bodybuilding.com/images/2020/xdb/cropped/xdb-81e-bench-press-m2-square-130x130.jpg"
srcset = "https://www.bodybuilding.com/images/2020/xdb/cropped/xdb-81e-bench-press-m2-square-130x130.jpg 1x, https://www.bodybuilding.com/images/2020/xdb/cropped/xdb-81e-bench-press-m2-square-200x200.jpg 2x" >
    </a> </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**My code with loop**

```
    const nodes = element.querySelectorAll('.cms-article-list__content--container')
    
    for (let i = 1; i < nodes + 1; i++) {

        const ExerciseGroupTitle = await page.$eval(
            `.cms-article-list__content--group-title`,
            (el) => el.innerText
        );
        console.log(ExerciseGroupTitle)

        const ExerciseGroupDescription = await page.$eval(
            `.cms-article-list__content--group-description`,
            (el) => el.innerText
        );
        console.log(ExerciseGroupDescription)

        const ExerciseName = await page.$eval(
            `.cms-article-workout__exercise--info`,
            (el) => el.innerText
        );
        console.log(ExerciseName)

        const ExerciseSets = await page.$eval(
            `.cms-article-workout__sets--definition > span`,
            (el) => el.innerText
        );
        console.log(ExerciseSets)

    }
```

**Edit**
this is the result it gave me after updating the element that is wrapping the table. It is not going through list of all the items.

```
[
  [
    'BARBELL BENCH PRESS (WARM-UP SETS)',
    'Use light weight and perform 2 sets of 5-10 reps, stopping each set short of failure.',
    'Barbell Bench Press - Medium Grip',
    '2 sets, 5-10 reps (rest 1 min.)'
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

`querySelectorAll()` exists in the browser (document) context, you can only use it inside `evaluate()` functions. In the puppeteer (Node.js) context you can try [`page.$$(selector)`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageselector-1).

So your code can be rewritten in such variants:

```js
const nodes = await page.$$('.cms-article-list__content--container');

for (const node of nodes) {
    const ExerciseGroupTitle = await node.$eval(
        `.cms-article-list__content--group-title`,
        (el) => el.innerText
    );
    console.log(ExerciseGroupTitle)

    const ExerciseGroupDescription = await node.$eval(
        `.cms-article-list__content--group-description`,
        (el) => el.innerText
    );
    console.log(ExerciseGroupDescription)

    const ExerciseName = await node.$eval(
        `.cms-article-workout__exercise--info`,
        (el) => el.innerText
    );
    console.log(ExerciseName)

    const ExerciseSets = await node.$eval(
        `.cms-article-workout__sets--definition > span`,
        (el) => el.innerText
    );
    console.log(ExerciseSets)
}
```

Or:

```js
const innerTexts = await page.evaluate(
  () => {
    const nodes = [...document.querySelectorAll('.cms-article-list__content--container')];
    const texts = nodes.map(node => [
      node.querySelector(`.cms-article-list__content--group-title`).innerText,
      node.querySelector(`.cms-article-list__content--group-description`).innerText,
      node.querySelector(`.cms-article-workout__exercise--info`).innerText,
      node.querySelector(`.cms-article-workout__sets--definition > span`).innerText,
    ]);
    return texts;
  }
);
console.log(innerTexts);
```

---

Test:

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, defaultViewport: null });

try {
  const [page] = await browser.pages();

  await page.goto('https://www.bodybuilding.com/profile/login');

  await page.type('input#login-username-input', '***');
  await page.type('input#login-password-input', '***');

  await Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation(),
    page.click('button#login-submit-button'),
  ]);

  await page.goto('https://www.bodybuilding.com/workout-plans/jim-stoppanis-12-week-shortcut-to-size/day/1');

  await page.waitForSelector('.cms-article-list__content--container');

  const innerTexts = await page.evaluate(
    () => {
      const nodes = [...document.querySelectorAll('.cms-article-list__content--container')];
      const texts = nodes.map(node => [
        node.querySelector(`.cms-article-list__content--group-title`)?.innerText,
        node.querySelector(`.cms-article-list__content--group-description`)?.innerText,
        node.querySelector(`.cms-article-workout__exercise--info`)?.innerText,
        node.querySelector(`.cms-article-workout__sets--definition > span`)?.innerText,
      ]);
      return texts;
    }
  );
  console.log(innerTexts);

} catch(err) { console.error(err); } finally { await browser.close(); }
```

Output:

```
[
  [
    'BARBELL BENCH PRESS (WARM-UP SETS)',
    'Use light weight and perform 2 sets of 5-10 reps, stopping each set short of failure.',
    'Barbell Bench Press - Medium Grip',
    '2 sets, 5-10 reps (rest 1 min.)'
  ],
  [
    null,
    null,
    'Barbell Bench Press - Medium Grip\n' +
      'Perform a rest-pause after the final set. See Training Guidelines for details.',
    '4 sets, 12-15 reps (rest 2 min.)'
  ],
  [
    null,
    null,
    'Barbell Incline Bench Press Medium-Grip\n' +
      'Perform a rest-pause after the final set. See Training Guidelines for details.',
    '3 sets, 12-15 reps (rest 2 min.)'
  ],
  [
    null,
    null,
    'Incline Dumbbell Flyes\n' +
      'Perform a rest-pause after the final set. See Training Guidelines for details.',
    '3 sets, 12-15 reps (rest 1 min.)'
  ],
  [
    null,
    null,
    'Cable Crossover\n' +
      'Perform a rest-pause after the final set. See Training Guidelines for details.',
    '3 sets, 12-15 reps (rest 1 min. )'
  ],
  [
    null,
    null,
    'Triceps Pushdown\n' +
      'Perform a rest-pause after the final set. See Training Guidelines for details.',
    '4 sets, 12-15 reps (rest 1 min.)'
  ],
  [
    null,
    null,
    'Dumbbell skullcrusher\n' +
      'Perform a rest-pause after the final set. See Training Guidelines for details.',
    '3 sets, 12-15 reps (rest 1 min.)'
  ],
  [
    null,
    null,
    'Low cable overhead triceps extension\n' +
      'Perform a rest-pause after the final set. See Training Guidelines for details.',
    '3 sets, 12-15 reps (rest 1 min. )'
  ],
  [
    null,
    null,
    'Standing Dumbbell Calf Raise\n' +
      'Perform a rest-pause after the final set. See Training Guidelines for details.',
    '3 sets, 25-30 reps (rest 1 min. )'
  ],
  [
    null,
    null,
    'Seated Calf Raise\n' +
      'Perform a rest-pause after the final set. See Training Guidelines for details.',
    '3 sets, 25-30 reps (rest 1 min. )'
  ]
]
```

Comment: The first code gave me this error `Error: Error: failed to find element matching selector ".cms-article-list__content--group-title"` and the 2nd one gave me this error: `Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null`

Comment: Well, I've added a test code with the HTML fragment you provided to the answer, it works without errors. It seems the wrapper elements in your full page may have some differences in the structure. So you just need to check if the child element exists before getting its text.

Comment: For example, you can use `?.innerText` to get undefined instead of errors for missing elements.

Comment: okay i changed what was wrapping around the table and it gave our the results in an array but it didn't loop through the next item in the table nor did it gave me an error. I updated my question to include the array that it gave out

Comment: is there a way I can message you since it requires login info? sorry about the inconvenience

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228054/discussion-between-bruce-mathers-and-vsemozhebuty).

Comment: I'm still hitting an error of `node.querySelector(`.cms-article-list__content--group-title`)?.innerText,`
`SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'`

I tried removing the question mark from all of them but then the error becomes `Cannot read property 'innerText' of null`. I don't understand why it's happening. I will message you my code

Comment: Could it be that you use either an old Node.js or an old Google Chrome without support for optional chaining (the `?.` syntax)? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#browser_compatibility